# Dialogflow bot integrated with Business Skype

Tags: azure, botframework, dialogflow-es, skype-for-business, azure-bot-service

I have a bot built with Dialogflow and works perfectly in Telegram and Skype channels. However I need it to be accessed through Skype for business.

Directly from Dialogflow, there is no such integration, so I decided to take a look at Microsoft bot framework where my Skype integration is hosted.

Right there I can see the Skype for business channel option but when I click it, I get prompted to migrate my bot to Azure bots because Skype for business channel is only available in Azure Bot Service.

[Skype for Business integration option in Microsoft Bor Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acmYp.png)

Anyone could help me out telling me if this migration will erase all of my bot's logic already built in Dialogflow, forcing me to re build my bot in azure bots service?

I really appreciate any help as I haven´t found any documentation or support regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't erase anything, and a Roll back migration button will be available in case you need to undo the migration.

The full documentation to that can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-migrate-bot?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a bot that is working and you only need to use the Azure Bot to integrate it with the existing channels, you can simply register your bot in the azure portal with the url to your bot.

[image: Azure Portal Registration]

Here is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) that will help you to register your bot.