# Getting skype user ids to dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, skype-for-business

I am creating a dialogflow to skype integration.With bot framework i am able to create the integration work.

I also referred the link below for the same.
[Dialogflow bot integrated with Business Skype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725385/dialogflow-bot-integrated-with-business-skype)

Is there way to identify the skype user and send the details to dialogflow.
As of now this is a generic request. I wanted to greet the user from his skype userid or username. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You must be getting some kind of ID in your request payload from skype to DialogFlow, check if skype provides any api to get user details.

Comment: It should be in an object in `agent.originalRequest`, have a look in your stackdriver logs.

Comment: @NathanLiu So will it automatically come without any extra configuration?

Comment: @lostCoder I believe so. This is how I get Facebook user ID, caller ID for telephony and From number with Twilio, with no config.

Answer (score 1):

this will be under originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.user in your request payload from dialogFlow

```
"originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "source": "skype",
    "payload": {
     "user": {
          "name": "Sana Zehra",
          "id": "29:1I3o3Np8sTLU7YSuhHO-IDuc1SgqMwg-83YwGryAZceE"
        },
        "timestamp": "2019-01-02T09:59:59.12Z"
      },
      "source": "skype"
    }
  }
```

You are also getting user name here in order to greet him.